# Show button with JS when span.class exists

Tags: javascript, button, hide

I have a button which toggles classes with a "price" to display and hide on my page. But when there is no class with "price" on the page, the button shouldn't be visible.

Since I have no idea how to work properly with JS, I need to rely on google but I didn't find something that worked. Hope you can help me.

Since it's on wordpress, I need it to work without jQuery.

```js
object.onload = function displaycataloguebutton() {

    var element = document.getElementsbyClassName("cataloguetoggle")
    for (i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
        element[i].classList.remove('cataloguedisplay');
    }
}

function hidePrices() {

    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("price");
    for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].classList.toggle('hideprice');
    }
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("cataloguetoggle")
    for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].classList.toggle('cataloguebuttonactive');
    }
}
```

```css
.hideprice {
    display: none !important;
}
.cataloguebuttonactive{
    background-color:#5cdb5c !important;
}
.cataloguedisplay{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<button class="cataloguetoggle cataloguedisplay" onclick="hidePrices()">Catalog</button>
```

Comment: what exactly is `object.onload`

Comment: Wordpress comes with jQuery. You can't use `$` by default though. Anyway, try this: https://jsfiddle.net/u4dtcm8y/

Comment: @DeC since Iam not that familiar with JS I thought there needs to be an initial "start" to start the script. So I just tried to start it with onload.

Comment: @ChrisG ah, I didn't know that. I tried your code and it works for the price-toggle but the button-toggle itself doesn't work. It's visible on any page or on no page if I use the display:none cataloguedisplay class

Comment: Don't use any extra CSS, just the code I provided minus the example <span>s.

Comment: @ChrisG I did! I deleted all of the CSS but one for the background-color toggle of the button. For this I tried to add some jQuery but obviously, it doesn't work. I tried to copy your code and reproduce it but it's not the way I guess.
This is everything I have: https://jsfiddle.net/ey0p8rx3/

And the button still shows when there is no .price class on the page

Comment: Is your site online so I can take a look?

Comment: @ChrisG Sadly the site is behind a register wall since it's a business b2b site where I can't offer access. But it seems, that the "hidden" attribute on the button doesn't work. But I see the attribute when I use the developer tools. When I inspect the events in there it says "function() {
  jQuery(".price").toggle();
}"
and "function(e) {
  return "undefined" != typeof S && S.event.triggered !== e.type ? S.event.dispatch.apply(t, arguments) : void 0
}"

Comment: @ChrisG Since it's a button, my theme edits "display:inline-flex". When I remove it, the button is gone. Even when there's a price on the page. Maybe it's because of that.

Comment: @ChrisG okay so I added to my .css "[hidden]{ display:none !important}" and the button is gone when it has the hidden attribute. BUT it's gone on the pages where prices are and on the pages where none are, it's still there. It's reversed like it should be